# Riverpod : how to listen to an async stream provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have an async stream provider (details omitted for clarity - basically it delivers a stream of Strings):

```
final mqttStreamProvider = StreamProvider<String>((ref) async* {
  final wsClient = ref.watch(mqttClientProvider.future);
  final service = await wsClient;

  await for (final value in service.getMessageStream()) {
    yield value;
  }
});
```

My understanding is that the right way to handle messages that don't result in a UI impact (no rebuild) is to use :
`ref.listen(...)`
in the build method of the top level widget of my application.

However, I can't find any example on how to listen to an async stream provider.
Any help on how to do this much appreciated!

Comment: you aren't transforming the stream, so it'd be easier to simply "return service.getMessageStream()" and make the function async instead of async*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just after asking the answer came :-)

```
ref.listen(mqttStreamProvider, (prev, next) {
      print("new stream value $next");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `watch` for your `StreamProvider` inside the `build` method

```
final steamAsync = ref.watch(mqttStreamProvider);
```

and then you can use `AsyncValue.when` like this,

```
return Scaffold(
  body: steamAsync.when(
    data: (data) {
      // return widget with data
    }
    error: (err, s) {
      // return error widget
    }
    loading: () {
      // return loading widget
    }
  ),
);
```

I believe that in this way you can handle your error and loading state easily.

Also, you can skip loading or error using,

```
steamAsync.when(
  skipError: true,
  skipLoadingOnRefresh: true,
  skipLoadingOnReload: true,
  .
  .
  .
}
```